# Swift resize or minimise UITableView in ViewController programatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, dropdown

I have tried to search online for resize the UITableView(not UITableView cell) so that when I click the button, the tableview will minimise while the contrast of two button get closer.

TableView does provide ".hidden" function to hide itself, but it will leave a big blank space between those 2 buttons in User Interface.

So I plan to minimise the height of tableview while hidden it, but I only can get help to resize "UITableView Cell" and not "UITableView" itself.

Does there have anyway to resize TableView or adjust the UI contrast programatically?

[image: button did not get closer while tableview hidden]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: set frame of the 2nd button when you are hiding the tableView . set x and y pos of button 2 as of the tableView .

Comment: @ioslearner, yea, I using auto layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you views are frame based, you can simply set the TableView as hidden, and move the second button up by setting second button's origin.y like:

`origin.y -= TableView.bounds.size.height`

If you are using auto layout, simply change TableView's height constraint to 0 and change second button's top layout the same way as frame.

A more simpler way if you are using auto layout is, make the second button's top to TableView's bottom, so when you set the TableView's height constraint to 0, the second button will automatically move up.

Remember, when you are using auto layout, you change the constraints like how you change the frames. They are just different concepts, but internally, auto layout engine will translate the constraints into frame values.

Comment: @SukhdeepSinghKalra help me understand more on your explanation, but since you are faster so i mark you as correct one

Comment: @LiewTzeHau thanks pal, I assume you already knows what I meant when describing constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Get the Constraint Of TableView Height from Storyboard.

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView_Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**After that set the value of this table view constraint to 0**

```
tableView_Height.constant = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

apply following steps

> 1) take tableHeight constraint outlet
>
> 2) in numberOfRowsInSection.
>   if rowcount is equal to zero then set tableviewHeight constant to zero before return the rowcount.
>
> 3)if you want to set tableheight according its row count then set tableviewheight constant equal to *((totalrow*cellheight)+fixsomespace)* in numberOfRowsInSection method. and aply some limit like if (height>300) then put it static height = 300